# Set column Width R data frame

Tags: r

I am building an R vignette with multiple data tables the full width is the same everywhere but i am trying to set the width of the first column the same so it aligns nicely.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, or more information about what your problem looks like, and what your desired result looks like. It's impossible to help you if all you tell us is "the column width isn't right".

Comment: Provide some detail? Maybe a small example? Are you using knitr or Sweave for the vignette? Are you compiling to PDF or HTML? What are you using to produce the tables? Are then in "display" code, like a LaTeX tabular environment or a HTML table, or just the R printed code output? What is making the width of the first column vary? Does it contain strings or numbers? If strings, are you okay truncating and do you need to?  Do you always have the same number of columns in your tables?